# How to to do smoke testing for Azure Data Factory based pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory, smoke-testing

I have On-premise SQL Server->ADF->Storage->ADF->Azure SQL pipeline. I'm using Azure DevOps.
ADF pipelines are executed every night and ADF monitor displays errors if such exists.

I wonder if there is ADF or other frameworks for doing build specific smoke testing before functional testing etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no in-built feature in ADF to perform smoke testing. You need to manage it programmatically.

Alternatively, instead of triggering the pipeline directly it's better to run the debug and check for any error. There is also Mapping data flow **debug mode** for Data Flow pipelines which actually runs each step in the data flow before executing/triggering the final pipeline.

[image]

You can visit [Integrating Smoke Tests into your Continuous Delivery Pipeline](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/integrating-smoke-tests-into-your-continuous-delivery-pipeline/) and check if this can be applied to your case.